# Website CSS and image updates not refreshing on mobile devices

Tags: css, image, version, updates

I have a PHP include in the head section of pages of my website, the include links to css files. In this include I can increase the version number of the css links and any revised content will be refreshed as the latest version in desktop browsers but my Samsung phone doesn't seem to refresh, even after me manually deleting the browsing history on the phone, the old images still show.

Is there any way to assure that all devices get fed the latest version of the website and all the files on it?

The css include in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:320px)" href="css/style-small.php?v=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1000px)" href="css/style-medium.php?v=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1400px)" href="css/style-large.php?v=1" />
```

Example of a normal html page and head section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>A Title</title>
<?php include_once ('includes/css.php'); ?>
<script src="js/placeholders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=200" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="author" content="the author" />
<meta name="Description" content="Standard description of content" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="my,website" />
</head>
```

Comment: Clear the cache. Not sure what browsing history has to do with anything. You could try the appropriate `<meta>` tags or HTTP headers that control caching.

Comment: Can you supply example code?

Comment: Edited comment, included some code. I can try instead of <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=200" /> this <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />  maybe?

Comment: @Xufox I tried "no store" still the same on my mobile. When I mentioned history, it's the only option to delete site data on the phone.

Comment: I just tried adding version numbers to the css references of the images which aren't refreshing, still the same on mobile but my desktop browsers all refreshed.

Comment: Extra info: I'm using my home WIFI to connect. I just deleted all data including login cookie and manually logged in again and voila now the latest images are showing. Weird bug.